# What is the location of the loaded theme icons?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

I am creating a simple file browser in python, gtk. I need to find a way to load the icons of the current theme (ie. folder icons) and use them in my code. Is there a location that always holds the current icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be in GTK Stock icons.

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-stock-items.html